# How to initialize an object of a class using curly brackets {}

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list, list-initialization

I'm looking to make this code compiled with no error (and without using std::initializer_list)
Here's the code :

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    T* Arr;
    int Size = 0;
    int Capacity = 1;
    Vector();
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector() {
    Arr=new T[1];
}
int main()
{
    Vector<int>V1 = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
}
```

Here's the Error :

```
Error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Vector<int>'
```

Comment: *without using std::initializer_list* Why use such a restriction?  It was literally made for this purpose

Comment: How do you expect to use an `initializer_list` constructor, without using `initializer_list`?

Comment: Since you are trying to get this code to compile without using std::initializer_list, yet the code has a std::initializer_list in it, you may need to insert this at the very beginning `/*` and this at the very end `*/`.  Then it will compile, although it won't link successfully (because it is missing `main`).

Comment: Eljay , nice one.

Comment: Eljay , do you know how to make a function that take variable number of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to initialize an object of a class using curly brackets {}
>
> ```
> Vector<int>V1 = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
> ```

Option 1: Use `std::initializer_list`.

> (and without using std::initializer_list)

Well, then use one of the other options:

Option 2: Make the class an aggregate. You initialise the members of the class with `{x, y, z}`. This approach is incompatible with your example.

Option 3: Use a variadic template constructor such as:

```
template<class... Args>
Vector(Args&& ...args)
```

Comment: @NathanOliver Why not? Worked fine in GCC and Clang when I tested it.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm confusing myself with trying to pass it to a function, not contructor overload resiolution